# In my GA4, why all my events is attributed to unassigned in channel grouping and (not set) in their source/ medium?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I wanted to ask a question since this has bothered me for quite a while, I had most (90%) of my conversion events in GA4 not only it gets attributed to Unassigned but the source/medium is also (not set), [GA4 Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxihL.png)

However this has happened with 2 of my GA4 accounts only, the rest is fine, is this because something wrong with how the website passes out its referrer? or it's because of something else? thank you!

I tried to:

1. Manually created parameters that passed down source/ medium manually using javascript that pulled out the value from cookies, but only worked when I was testing it, eventually, the unassigned number still piling up
2. Checking out the referrer value in console, network, utm, gclid, and it worked the same with the correct GA accounts I have. So why it doesn't work on this website?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when any event tags trigger before the config is loaded.

If you are using Gtag implementation then make sure that this line below from the gtag snippet already ran BEFORE the event:

```js
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
```

If you are implementing via Google Tag Manager`, then make sure that the configuration tag fires as early as possible (**Initialization All Pages**) and event tags rather later, for example on the **Load** event